# How tolerant against external changes to a working tree is libgit2 with a loaded repository object?

Tags: libgit2

Imagine you have a long running process which instantiates a `git_repository*` object at the program start. From time to time it is queried for commits (`git_commit_lookup`), checking repository state (`git_repository_head_unborn`), parsing and listing references (`git_revparse_single`, `git_reference_lookup`, `git_branch_iterator_new`, ...).

However, independent from this process there are other processes (e.g., vanilla git) working on and changing that working tree (e.g., committing, pulling, pushing, rebasing, creating branches, ...).

- Do I have to expect crashes based on e.g. outdated cached data (such as index structures or odb files) or mem-mapped files?
- Do I have to worry that I receive outdated data?
- Do I have to worry because libgit2 starts allocating more and more memory for caching?
- Or do I have to `git_repository_free` and get a "fresh" `git_repository*` pointer regularly?

I use Visual Studio 2013 (Update4) and when I work on the working tree it crashes from time to time in `git2-...dll`... So I wonder whether libgit2 is designed in general for such scenarios.

First tests with my own application suggest that no crashes occur, but this can, of course, depend on my specific tests...

Comment: If you're having issues with Visual Studio, you should report this to Microsoft. VS uses a custom version of libgit2 which the project cannot support.

Comment: I can't tell if you're asking about *your application* or actually asking about *VS 2013*.  If the latter, please upgrade to VS 2013 Update 4 and please report any bugs to us so that we can fix them.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thanks for your comments. VS2013 Update4 is crashing, but that is only a reason why I'm unsure whether or not libgit2 is usable in a scenario as described in the question in general.

Comment: @MrTux Understood.  Seriously though, please report bugs.

Comment: @EdwardThomson How to report bugs to MS? - For outsiders MS looks like a LED, there is only one way of interaction.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  :(  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio is the place.  It will get to us that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected that an instance of libgit2 will play nicely with other git clients (git.git, libgit2, jgit, etc).

> Do I have to expect crashes based on e.g. outdated cached data (such as index structures or odb files) or mem-mapped files?

You shouldn't, no.  We read the index into memory and operate on that.  If that were changed underneath, you might see *outdated* information, but you should not *crash*.  If you do, that would be a bug.

> Do I have to worry that I receive outdated data?

You'd need to clarify this with an actual scenario.  For example: with the index, if you load it with `git_index_load`, this reads the index into memory.  You can then operate on it.  If somebody else updates the index, then your data is indeed outdated.

If you are expecting heavy concurrency, you may wish to reload things.  For example, you can call `git_index_load` to reload the index if it has changed since it was last loaded.

> Do I have to worry because libgit2 starts allocating more and more memory for caching?

Caching is configured as a [libgit2 option](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/libgit2/git_libgit2_opts).  Its defaults are relatively moderate, but there are limits to the size of the cache.

> Or do I have to git_repository_free and get a "fresh" git_repository* pointer regularly?

I don't expect that there would be much benefit to this.